# Sometimes NullReferenceException was unhandled/Otherwise only display column name in gridview

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

There are some controls in *Form1* and a button named *Filter*. After the event `Filter_Clicked` is fired, the second form *Form2* opens. There are some input controls in *Form2* and a button named `Search`. After the `Search_Clicked` event is fired, the *Form2* sends a query to one of the methods in *Form1*. Then the result is displayed in  a `GridView` control of *Form1*.

My problem is that:

- I defines row data for each column, but when the result is displayed in the gridview, there is only column's name to see and row are empty even not display as NULL.
- I have tried calling *Form2* from *Form1* in two different ways and each one causes a  different result and warning:

Variant 1:

```
/* Result: Display only column name in Form1 gridview */
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var way1 = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form1>().Single();            
}
```

[image: Image Result of Variant 1]
The `Search_Clicked()` event looks like this:

```
String searchExam = comboBoxForExamFilter.SelectedItem.ToString();
String searchFilter = "select Exam_Name,Subject_Name,Marks,Status from ABC_SchoolDB.dbo.Sheet_Marks where Exam_Name= ' " + searchExam + " ' ";                
way1.userSqlQueryExecutor(searchFilter);
```

Note:

- when calling `userSqlQueryExecutor(searchQuery)` from Form1, it displays the table data
- Don't worry about sql injection

Variant 2:

```
/* Result: NullReferenceException was unhandled */
private Form1 way2;
public Form2(Form callForm1)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    way2 = callForm1 as Form1;            
}
```

The `Search_Clicked()` event looks like this:

```
way2.userSqlQueryExecutor(searchFilter);
```

How do i show all my row data in the `GridView` control?

Comment: Where is the GridView control? How is the GridView control filled?

Comment: @Pasty I think you misunderstood in my question. Now, i added result images with additional information.

Comment: What and where exactly is the problem? What happens? What should happen instead (what is the expected result)?

Comment: One problem were solved that the `Variant 1:` given results. I given unwanted space in the `searchQuery`. But what about `Variant 2:`. Why it cause `NullReferenceException was unhandled`. Please find it causes.

Comment: Since you know exactly where your `NullReferenceException` is appearing, you can try to debug your own programm. This article will give you an idea how an where to start:[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: This is the line `way2.userSqlQueryExecutor(searchFilter);` where `NullReferenceException was unhandled`.